# How to get the list of installed windows services using SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, service

Can you please help me how to get the list of installed windows services using an SQL Query?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Expanded answer: well, technically you can write SQLCLR procedure and get installed services via call of this procedure. But it is all about .NET and has nothing to do with query itself.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Thanks for your comment. We can start or stop the service using an SQL Job. I got this query whether can we get the whole list of windows services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`xp_cmdshell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) (which must be [enabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190693.aspx) on the server) to invoke [sc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb490995.aspx):

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Cmd(
    Line_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Line VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #Cmd(Line)
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'sc queryex type= service state= all'

SELECT SUBSTRING(Line, 15, 100)
FROM #Cmd
WHERE Line LIKE 'SERVICE_NAME%'
```

If you need to get more info about a service, you can use the `Line_ID` line to self-join and show relevant lines:

```sql
SELECT   SUBSTRING(l1.Line, 15, 100) AS Service_Name
        ,SUBSTRING(l2.Line, 15, 100) AS Display_Name
        ,SUBSTRING(l3.Line, 33, 100) AS Service_State
FROM #Cmd l1
    INNER JOIN #Cmd l2
        ON l1.Line_ID = l2.Line_ID - 1
    INNER JOIN #Cmd l3
        ON l1.Line_ID = l3.Line_ID - 3
WHERE l1.Line LIKE 'SERVICE_NAME%'
```

Comment: @METALHEAD, I added an example for showing more info about each service.